# Multi select Drop down in Struts2

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

```
<div class="select_wrap">
    <select name="sampleselect"  class="select_field" multiple="multiple" >

        <option>Select Id  </option>
        <s:iterator value="userList" var="usrList" status="s">
        <option value=<s:property value="#usrList"></s:property>><s:property value="#usrList"></s:property></option>

        </s:iterator>
    </select>
    </div>      
<br /><br />
            <s:submit value="Compliance Export" name="Export Data" align="left" action="exportExcelAction4"/>
```

usrList is getting populated from database

In my action class

```
private List<String> sampleselect=new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getSampleselect() {
        return sampleselect;
    }


    public void setSampleselect(List<String> sampleselect) {
        this.sampleselect = sampleselect;
    }
```

But this sample select is not getting populated.

Comment: You need to populate `userList` not `usrList`.

Answer (score 2):

The `list` attribute is used to get the iterable source, while the `name` attribute is used to set the selected item. Also use the `<s:select/>` tag for a cleaner (and much easier) code. For example:

Struts.xml

```xml
<action name="firstAction" class="foo.bar.FirstAction">
    <result>firstPage.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="secondAction" class="foo.bar.SecondAction">
    <result>secondPage.jsp</result>
</action>
```

FirstAction.java

```
private List<String> userList;

/* Getter and Setter */

public String execute(){
    // Load your data from database
    userList = getMyService().findUserList();
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

FirstPage.jsp

```xml
<s:form action="secondAction" >
    <div class="select_wrap">
        <s:select list = "userList"
                  name = "selectedItem"
              cssClass = "select_field"
              multiple = "multiple" />
    </div>

    <s:submit value="Post your selection to second Action" />
</s:form>
```

SecondAction.java

```
private String selectedItem;

/* Getter and Setter */ 

public String execute(){
    log.debug("Selected item is: " + selectedItem);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

SecondPage.jsp

```xml
<div>
    Selected item is: <s:property value="selectedItem" />
</div>
```

Comment: userList is getting populated from database.

Comment: I have changed to  <div class="select_wrap">
    <s:select label="Select Id " name="sampleselect" class="select_field" headerKey="0" headerValue="Select Id" multiple="true" list="userList1"/> 
 </div>    
<br /><br />
      <s:submit value="Compliance Export" name="Export Data" align="left" action="exportExcelAction4"/>
       </div>    but still not working

Comment: Im getting this error   tag 'select', field 'list', name 'sampleselect': The requested list key 'userList1' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location] in my action class

Comment: I've edited, hope you have no more doubts now. Also care about using `cssClass` instead of `class` when using struts tags. Remember to accept & upvote if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Struts2 tag `<s:select>` rather than an iterator over  elements. Also, your sampleselect variable is initialized, but it has no items in it.

Your Action should have:

```
private List<String> sampleselect = Arrays.asList("some", "data", "items");
```

Then your JSP can have:

```
<s:select list="sampleselect" multiple="true"/>
```

Ref: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/select.html